# How do i put separator after each 5 string in 20 random strings?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-3, text-editing, notepad

Hello guys i want to know how do i put separators such as "-" or ":" after each 5 string
in 20 random letters&numbers string of many lines using regex?

So basically count 5 from left to right then put separator and so on till the end of 20 strings which mean 4x separators.

**Sample:**

```
8NUS9IYXGITH015SUWPS
DDJK1U9ISK6BCAPN66WA
8S7RGFPWENQUHCERKV1K
VAUPAQAZ1AP2SZC54C39
8D5CK2Y8F0OMLB4XL5KY
606PR72MQBG63AMHX5EU
```

**Output Result:**

```
8NUS9-IYXGI-TH015-SUWPS
DDJK1-U9ISK-6BCAP-N66WA
8S7RG-FPWEN-QUHCE-RKV1K
VAUPA-QAZ1A-P2SZC-54C39
8D5CK-2Y8F0-OMLB4-XL5KY
606PR-72MQB-G63AM-HX5EU
```

Comment: what have you tried ? edit and add them to your question

Comment: i just show an example of how the lines look like and how i want them and yeah i edit them manually, i want regex to do this automatically for any lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.{5}\K(?!$)`
- Replace with: `-`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.{5}        # 5 any character but newline
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(?!$)       # negative lookahead, make we haven't end of line after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: What do i say, Toto you are a genius completely Legend, thank you so much for the regex work perfectly and not just notepad++ even it works in another text editor Emeditior but i had to Check on Regular Expression Can Match Newline Characters, Much appreciated man i spend many hours trying to do it you saved my day.

Comment: @DeathRival: You're welcome, glad it helps.